# Does com.sun.faces.context.RequestMap belong to the JSF API?

Tags: lotus-notes

requestScope is a com.sun.faces.context.RequestMap object, I found its methods reference at http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/sun/faces/context/RequestMap.html. I wonder if it belongs to the JSF API. 
The packages here http://www.docjar.com/projects/Mojarra-2.0.1-code.html are different from the official reference here: download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/index.html. It seems the packages have been moved into javax.*. So what version is XPage based on?

Comment: I found from the XPage extensibility API http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/lotus/Domino-Designer/JavaDocs/XPagesExtAPI/8.5.2/index.html XPage is build upon the javax.faces.* packages.

Answer (score 0):

Erik Brooks has an [article](http://www.bleedyellow.com/blogs/erik/entry/xpages_are_not_modern) about this. Or take a look at the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPages) page.
XPages are based on JSF 1.2

Comment: Maybe my questions were misleading. What I really want to know are 
1. Does com.sun.faces.context.RequestMap belong to the JSF API?
2. What's the relation between packages com.sun.faces.* and javax.faces.*, are the former obsolete and why are they involved in the current xpage?

Answer (score 0):

I learned the answer after I knew more about J2EE.  JSF API is only the specification. com.sun.faces.* and similar things are concrete implementations.